# jquery create a div in a div instead of a stack

Tags: jquery, html

I try to create a div inside a div and inside that an image.
This is my attempt:

```
$("#images").append('<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4"></div>')
                          .append('<div class="div-content"></div>')
                          .append("<img>").attr( "src", item.media.m );
```

Instead of that it just creates a stack like this:

```
<div id="images" src="https://farm4.staticflickr.com/3842/14497175986_683bd74acf_m.jpg">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="div-content"></div>
    <img>
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4"></div>
    <div class="div-content"></div>
    <img>
```

what would be the proper way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery functions tend to return the original object to allow for chaining - so in this case all the calls to `append` and the call to `attr` are being done on `#images`.  If you do want to build it up in this way, you'll need to split it up a little:

```
var i = $("<img>").attr( "src", item.media.m );
var d2 = $('<div class="div-content"></div>');
var d = $('<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4"></div>');
d2.append(i);
d.append(d2);
$("#images").append(d);
```

Comment: it's useful if you're within a loop and need to append multiple times at the same level - declare a variable to the level you want to append at outside of your loop and keep appending to it within the loop

Answer (score 1):

You can always just do it all in 1 line:

```
$("#images").append('<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4"><div class="div-content"><img src="' + item.media.m + '"/></div></div>')
```

Answer (score 0):

you're appending several element in images so they are not nested.
Try

```
$("#images").append('<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4"></div>');
$(".col-xs-12").append('<div class="div-content"></div>');
$("div-content").append('img ...');
```

..or simply all at once